# Django: unable to save model - Err: "id" expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey...>

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm really out of ideas here, I tried everything.
Basically I'm just trying to save some item whereas the `owner` is a foreign key related to the default Django `User` Model. This same methods works for other views and models, where the association is identically. But here I get this error:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: owner>.
```

This is my model:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

""" ... """

class Item(TimeStampMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Items")
    last_bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="bidded_objects", default=owner)
    etc=etc...
```

This is my view:

```py
class Form_New_Item(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'price', 'category', 'image_url']

def create_new_item(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.method == "POST":
        form = Form_New_Item(request.POST)
        user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            new_item = Item(
                owner=user,
                title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
                etc=etc...,
            )
            new_item.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

Notice the error happens when I call `new_item.save()`:

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me.

Comment: what is `eec=ecc` where is that coming from.

Comment: sorry @Martins I mean etc (etcetera), to avoid reporting all the other properties that for the sake of this example I think they are superfluous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it, I should have provided the entire Item class on the example sorry for that (I just edit the first message), now I see more clearly where the error was:

I have a property of the class that depends on another property.

```py
owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
last_bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="bidded_objects", default=owner)
```

So you see the second property `last_bidder` have as default the first one `owner`.

Despite the fact that the error Django report seems to be about `owner` property, the problem was on `last_bidder` one.

I solved it by setting `null=True` instead of a default with the first property:

```py
last_bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="bidded_objects", null=True)
```